# Prove $|\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{y^2+1}| < |x-y|$ when $x\neq y$

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to prove the basic formula for contraction mapping as an extension of an undergraduate homework problem I had, and have found this to be true using a calculator but can't figure out how to do it formally or even intuitively.

$|\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{y^2+1}| < |x-y|$ when $x\neq y$

Comment: Classic case where it is useful to multiply by $1$. This time it is a good idea to write $1= \frac{\sqrt{x^+1}+ \sqrt{y^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+ \sqrt{y^2+1}}$. Also, you want to exclude the case $x=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \ne y$, we have $\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{y^2+1} = \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}} = \dfrac{(x-y)(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}} $ so we need to show that:
$$ \left| \frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}} \right| < |x-y| \iff |x+y| < \left| \sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1} \right|$$
Which is clearly true.

Comment: The case $x=y$ is not trivial, but false (unless you claim $0<0$). Also instead of "clearly true" the following argument would be more convincing $$ \vert x + y\vert \leq \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert = \sqrt{x^2} + \sqrt{y^2} < \sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1} = \vert \sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1} \vert $$ where we first use the triangle inequality and then the monotonicity of the square root. Anyways, nice answer :)

Comment: Thanks, @SeverinSchraven you're right, it's not a strict inequality - I edited it

Answer (score 0):

Elementary Calculus also works. The derivative of $f(t)=\sqrt{t^2+1}$ is
$f'(t)=\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$. If $x\neq y$, then without loss of generality we have $|x|<|y|$, and we have
$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(|x|)-f(|y|)|$, so by the Mean Value Theorem there exists some $|x|<t<|y|$ such that
$$|f(|x|)-f(|y|)|=||x|-|y||\cdot |f'(t)|<|x-y|$$
whereby the inequalities $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$ and $\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}<1$ (for all $t> 0$) were used.